# Bad results on odd-numbered pages when querying New York Times Article Search API

Tags: python, while-loop, iteration

I'm trying to run a search using the [New York Times' Article Search API v 2](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/read/article_search_api_v2?pagewanted=all). The way the API works, for queries with more than 10 results, the results are separated into pages, and you must request each page separately. So for instance, to get results 1-10, include "page=0" in the request. For results 1-11, it's "page=1", and so on.

I want to grab all the results. (On the query I'm testing, there are 147.) The following code works only on EVEN-NUMBERED pages. So it returns results just fine when the count is 0, 2, 4. On odd-numbered requests, it seems to successfully query the API -- it returns a "Status": "OK" value -- but the list of "docs", where results are generally stored, is empty.

I can't for the life of me figure out why. Any ideas?

```
from nytimesarticle import articleAPI
import time

#initialize API
api = articleAPI(API_key)

#conduct search
def custom_search(page_number):
  articles = api.search( q = query, page = page_number)
  return articles

count = 0

while True:

  #get first set of articles
  articles = custom_search(count)

  #print all the headlines
  for article in articles['response']['docs']:
    print "%s\nDate: %s\t%s\n" % (article['headline']['main'],
                                  article['pub_date'], count)

  #iterate the page number
  count += 1

  #pause to avoid rate limits
  time.sleep(2)
```